# MapInfo to layered pdf with linked layered legends

Tags: mapinfo, pdf

I am trying to make a layered pdf of Rock geochemistry thematic map from MapInfo of several different elements on same base so I can present a clean 1 page pdf map with the ability to view or unview the different elements values with the appropriate legend with one click.  I get it all to work except the legends will not come in as separate layers attached to proper map. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I came across that issue, too, a while back.

I don't think MapInfo Pro links the legends to the layers in the map in the PDF. So there's no way to hide the legend for a single layer when you turn that layers visibility to off.

You will have to view all legends all the time.

The only possible solution that comes to my mind is to have multiple maps each with one thematic map in the layout.

This would make it possible to show/hide the individual maps in the PDF